# ReactiveMongo query returning None

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am just new to learning Scala and the related technologies.I am coming across the problem where the loadUser should return a record but its coming empty.

I am getting the following error:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

I appreciate this is not ideal Scala, so feel free to suggest me improvements.

```
class MongoDataAccess extends Actor {
  val message = "Hello message"

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case data: Payload => {
      val user: Future[Option[User]] = MongoDataAccess.loadUser(data.deviceId)
      val twillioApiAccess = context.actorOf(Props[TwillioApiAccess], "TwillioApiAccess")
      user onComplete {
        case Failure(exception) => println(exception)
        case p: Try[Option[User]] => p match {
          case Failure(exception) => println(exception)
          case u: Try[Option[User]] => twillioApiAccess ! Action(data, u.get.get.phoneNumber, message)
        }
      }
    }

    case _ => println("received unknown message")
  }
}

object MongoDataAccess extends MongoDataApi {
  def connect(): Future[DefaultDB] = {
    // gets an instance of the driver
    val driver = new MongoDriver
    val connection = driver.connection(List("192.168.99.100:32768"))

    // Gets a reference to the database "sensor"
    connection.database("sensor")
  }

  def props = Props(new MongoDataAccess)

  def loadUser(deviceId: UUID): Future[Option[User]] = {
    println(s"Loading user from the database with device id: $deviceId")
    val query = BSONDocument("deviceId" -> deviceId.toString)

    // By default, you get a Future[BSONCollection].
    val collection: Future[BSONCollection] = connect().map(_.collection("profile"))

    collection flatMap { x => x.find(query).one[User] }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranty the find-one (`.one[T]`) matches at least one document in your DB, so you get an `Option[T]`.

Then it's up to you to consider (or not) that having found no document is a failure (or not); e.g.

```
val u: Future[User] = x.find(query).one[User].flatMap[User] {
  case Some(matchingUser) => Future.successful(matchingUser)
  case _ => Future.failed(new MySemanticException("No matching user found"))
}
```

> Using `.get` on `Option` is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: That is going to require the signature of the function from Future[Option[User]] to Future[User] which is deceiving for the calling code as it might or might not get a User once the Future is completed. Anyway, changes you suggested still returned None.

Comment: If a `Future(Option.empty[T])` is returned, it simply means there is no matching document.

Comment: MongoDB query db.getCollection('profile').find({"deviceId": "03af30d0-4dc6-11e6-beb8-9e71128cae77"}) returns the right document.

Comment: Please check how you call it (same collection, same String value). This basic use case is (of course) something covered by the [tests of the driver](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/test/scala/CommonUseCases.scala#L123).